# Cannot ping myhostname without using myhostname.local

Tags: networking

I use my ubuntu 12.04 laptop across many network and I need to make my hostname (internally from my very laptop) pingable or 'http' accessible with the ip address assigned me by the dhcp servers of the network I connect to.
if I ping myhostname I have the result: 'myhostname unknown host'.
if I ping myhostname.local i'm replied correctly with the ip i'm expecting (the one assigned me by the dhcp server).
I tried adding the string 'local' (without hyphens) in the search box of the connection in NetworkManager... no way.
I tried adding the string 'domain local' in the head file of the resolvconf.d folder... no way.
I tried installing samba... same behaviour.
How can I make myhostname search be defaulted to myhostname.local without updating /etc/hosts everytime I change network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, and interested to know myself, but if you're just trying to access yourseld you can always use 127.0.0.1 or **localhost**

Comment: I can ping HomeLaptop (my compur name)...

Comment: I usually start lampp and oracle-tns listeners. I usually use them locally so I could use 127.0.0.1 but sometimes I need to show test results to customers on the network i'm connected to so I need to start them on the interface attached to the network (to make them visible internally and to the network via the ip adddress)

Comment: School.boy forgetting... I have vmware installed... The vmware service starts a virtual network and this network seems to capture the resolving (i don't know how) of the "Myhost" name. Infact: ping myhostname.local resolves to the ip address assigned by dhcp on the host network, ping myhostname (without .local) resolves to the virtual interface of vmware. Stopping the vmware services reset the standard behaviour: ping myHostname resolves to myHostname.local an then to the ip of the external network i'm connected to.

Comment: just for @meccooll: take a look at this link [link](http://www.serenux.com/2009/09/howto-configure-ubuntu-to-be-able-to-use-and-respond-to-netbios-hostname-queries-like-windows-does/) an take a look at this file: `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Inside here are the directives: **send host-name yourhostname** and **append domain-search**.